# Callout shape is cut off when being resized on a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, callout

I'm using [Microsoft.Expression.Controls.Callout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.controls.callout%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to paint a callout object on a `Canvas`. Most of the time it looks fine, as below:
[image: Normal]

However, when it is resized, the anchor point (and part of the drop shadow) is somehow cut off:

[image: Cutoff]

I've tried to set different properties such as `SnapToDevicePixels`, `UseLayoutRounding` etc. but nothing works so far.

Here's the XAML (the callout object is used as the template for a control named `CalloutElement` which inherits from `Control`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Editor:CalloutElement}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Editor:CalloutElement}">
                <ed:Callout CalloutStyle="RoundedRectangle" Fill="#FFF"
                            StrokeThickness="2"
                            AnchorPoint="0.5 1.4">
                    <ed:Callout.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.5"/>
                    </ed:Callout.Effect>
                    <ed:Callout.Stroke>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                    </ed:Callout.Stroke>
                </ed:Callout>

                <!-- More XAML for resize adorner -->

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note that the resize adorner seemly displays the ovals at the corners allowing the callout to be resize. The code of the adorner only change the `Width` and `Height` of `CalloutElement`.

Any idea on why this occurs and how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by overriding [`GetLayoutClip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.getlayoutclip.aspx) method. Yes, kinda hacky, but works fine so far. Love to know if there's better solution.

```
protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by overriding: `MeasureOverride(Size constraint)`

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
    return constraint;
}
```